# Morita equivalence base equivalence relation for discrete groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, morita-equivalence

In the context of "discrete groups", is there an equivalence relation that implies the Morita equivalence of their reduced group C*-algebras?

We define $G \sim H$ for discrete groups $G$ and $H$, when $C^*_r (G)$ and $C^*_r (H)$ (or even their full group C*-algebras) are Morita equivalent as the two C*-algebras.

Does $\sim$ have an explicit description?

thanks

**PS:** By Alain Valette's first comment in below, the $C^*_r (-)$ case shouldn't be considered so the problem is about $C^*(-)$.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Of course! I mean which explicit relation is induced among the discrete groups. Let me precise my question. thanks

Comment: @Sebastian: Observe: $G\mapsto C^*(G)$ is indeed functorial, but $G\mapsto C^*_r(G)$ is not: the latter is functorial only for group monomorphisms; and whenever $C^*_r(G)$ is simple, i.e. frequently, you have a counter-example to functoriality in general, by looking at the map $G\rightarrow \{1\}$.

Comment: If two C*-algebras are Morita equivalent, they have equivalent representation theories and homeomorphic duals. For finite groups: $G \sim H$ if and only if $|\hat{G}|=|\hat{H}|$. For example the two-element group is equivalent in your sense to the symmetric group $Sym(3)$. May I ask whether you have non-trivial examples among torsion-free groups?

Comment: @AlainValette The infinite case is strange and I have no any example in this case. But I think existence of a torsion-free finitely generated group with finite number of conjugacy classes maybe give an negative answer to this question.

Comment: Could you please make your mind up whether you mean the full group Cstar algebras or the reduced group Cstar algebras, as per Alain Valette's comment. Also, @SebastianGoette you might wish to reconsider your opening statement?

Comment: @YemonChoi thanks for your notification

Comment: @Alain Valette, I am puzzled by your remark regarding $S_2$ and $S_3$. The first has two irreps while the second has three. Is this a typo, or am I missing something?

Comment: @YemonChoi Now that the question has been revised, I am perfectly happy. I was a bit hasty to claim that $C^*_r(-)$ is a functor. Even if it is not, it still makes sense to consider also the case where the relation $\sim$ is defined using $C^*_r$.

Comment: @user89334: Oops I meant the 3-element group! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment: let $G,H$ be countable, abelian, torsion-free groups. Claim: $C^*G\sim C^*H$ if and only if $G$ is isomorphic to $H$. To prove the non-trivial implication: denote by $\hat{G}$ the Pontryagin dual of $G$, a compact connected abelian group. Then $C^*G\simeq C(\hat{G})$ by Fourier transform. Since $C^*G\sim C^*H$, the groups $\hat{G}$ and $\hat{H}$ are homeomorphic, hence the first $\check{C}$ech cohomology groups $H^1(\hat{G},\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^1(\hat{H},\mathbb{Z})$ are the same. It remains to see that $H^1(\hat{G},\mathbb{Z})\simeq G$. Write $G=ind-lim_k G_k$, an inductive limit of finitely generated free abelian groups, i.e $G_k\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{n_k}$. Dualizing, $\hat{G}$ is a projective limit of tori, i.e. $\hat{G}=proj-lim_k \mathbb{T}^{n_k}$.Since $\check{C}$ech cohomology converts projective limits into inductive limits, we get $H^1(\hat{G},\mathbb{Z})=ind-lim_k H^1(\mathbb{T}^{n_k},\mathbb{Z})=ind-lim_k \mathbb{Z}^{n_k}=G$.

Comment: How much "countability" is important in your proof? I mean can the countable+abelian+torsion-free bing replaced with discrete+abelian+torsion-free?

Comment: @Shakiba: Indeed it seems that you can replace "countable" by "discrete", if you insist on dealing with huge groups. The reason is that Cech cohomology works well for arbitrary compact spaces, not only metrizable ones. Of course in the above argument you must then work with arbitrary directed sets, not only $\mathbb{N}$.